# Can't get "$set" (mongoose) working, i only need to update ONE vairable in my mongo DB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to make a function that ONLY updates the balance in my database (all the other variables need to be constant). I have read that I maybe need to use the set function, but I don't know hot to use it. Mabey someone that can help?

```
router.put('/:id', function (req, res, next) {

Account.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$set : {account.balance, req.body}}).then(function(account){
    Account.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(function(account){
        res.send("Account balance updated \n" + account);
    });
});
```

Account schema

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Jeg laver et "account" skema
const AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    // Alle som strings, udover "id"
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,

    client_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Client',
        required: true,
    },
    balance: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    alias: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    }
});
const model = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
module.exports = model;
```

Comment: Can you post a document example or the schema for account please?

Comment: it is up now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are querying twice and I don't know why.

You are doing `findByIdAndUpdate()` and into the callback you are finding the element again. I think this is to get the updated document. But there is a better way using `{new:true}` int this way:

```js
model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$set : {"account.balance", req.body}},{new: true},(error,doc)=>{
    console.log("doc = ",doc)
})
```

The other thing I see wrong (but without know the schema is not easy to know) is you are adding the entire `req.body` to the `balance` field. I don't know what `req.body` contains, but I suposse this need a change.

Look at this query, I think that's you want:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 0
},
{
  "$set": {
    "balance": 20
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SQtjFtxyIPe)

`$set` is used with the field you want to update. In this case `balance`.

Note that the new object is simply a number, and I think your `req.body` is an entire object. And that's why this is not updated.

Using `mongoose` try something like this:

```js
var balance = req.body.balance; //or whatever you get the value, but remember, it expects a Number

model.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": req.params.id}, {"$set" : {"balance", balance}},{new: true},(error,doc)=>{
    console.log("doc = ",doc)
})
```

Comment: I have also tried to use the account.balance, but it will not work, it just says SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: Use double quotes: "account.balance". But, with your schema is not neccesary, you only need "balance".

Comment: Thanks so much, the mistake was that i tried to save an entire object to the balance field. I just changes req.body to req.body.balance, and everything worked fine :)

thanks a lot <3

Comment: You are welcome! Also if the problem has been solved, mark answer as accepted is apreciated